# Laravel Schedule Has No Effect In Elastic Beantstalk CRON Job

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run cron job using laravel scheduler I wrote the scheduled in the Kernel to be as follows:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {

        $schedule->call(function(){
            Log::channel('channel')->info("testing cron job :)");
        })
        ->everyMinute()
        ->thenPing("https://cronhub.io/ping/b3e3f120-e041-11ea-b67f-ff1be350e0bb");
    }
```

and when I test the job locally using the command: `php artisan schedule:run` it runs successfully and I got the log in my slack channel.

I am using ElasticBeanstalk for my infrastructure hence, I am trying to setup the needed configuration using `.ebextensions` and I have a file for that which is: `.ebextensions/cron-setup.confi` and its content is as follows:

```
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/cron_example":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      * * * * * cd /var/app/current && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

commands:
  rm_old_cron:
    command: "rm -fr /etc/cron.d/cron_example.bak"
    ignoreErrors: true
```

When I deploy my code to the server I found that the cron job is running successfully by looking at both the `/var/log/cron` log file + the SaaS debugger that I am using for making a bing once the job is executed. However, there is no effect for that execution at all. In other words, I am not getting the slack message and to make sure it's not related to env vars or any other reason I tried to run the command: `php artisan schedule:run` from the server and I received the message in slack, I also thought about that there might be a problem with communicating with slack (although it worked fine manually as mentioned) thus, I tried to make another job that is making some changes in the database and I got the exact same thing where it's working fine locally and in the server when applied manually, and it also works fine by reading the cron file but without any effect on the database!
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this correct syntax with double sheduler? `schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 schedule:run 1>>`?

Comment: nope, it's not. I just copied it wrongly from my code, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I would suggest logging to some file not in /dev/null maybe there some errors popup